# Regex: string that is made only of numbers and strings

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if the string is contained only of numbers and dashes no matter in what order. So that it would match these examples:

```
---56554-565-5995--- 
459566565
---------
-87848445445
5545---54
```

Any possible way that they can be mixed up. If any letter or any other character beside numbers or dashes appears on any of the spots it would return 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following regex

```
/^[\d-]+$/
```

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/nB7nG1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Knew it would be something simple. I'll go and think why this example works. Thank you very much

Comment: @JesusChrist : glad to help